# この型をC++で定義できますか？

Tags: c#, c++

以下はC#のコードです。
C++でaと等価な型は定義できるでしょうか？

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate a a();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            a x = f;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) x = x();
        }
        static a f() { Console.Write("f"); return g; }
        static a g() { Console.Write("g"); return f; }
    }
}
```

C++で関数ポインタを使い、実装したかなり近いコードが以下になりますが、
キャストが必須で、可能ならばキャストをなくしたいです。

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void *(*a)();
void *f();
void *g();
    
void *f() { puts("f"); return (void *)g; }
void *g() { puts("g"); return (void *)f; }

int main()
{
    a x = f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)x = (a)x();
    return 0;
}
```

私はC++では完全にキャストなしのaを定義できないのではないか？と疑っています。
aのポイントは関数の戻り値の型がその関数自身になっているところです。
C++でリストのクラスを作るとき

```
class Node
{
public:
    Item item;
    Node *nxt;
};
```

のような自分自身のポインタを定義に含めるような書き方をできると思うのですが、
今回のaのような関数と戻り値の場合、そのような書き方が用意されていないように思えるのです。

今回の質問の元ネタは5chの「なあ、再帰関数好きな人いる？ パート3」というスレの>>676になります。
https://mevius.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/tech/1448704298/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C/C++では自分自身と同じ型を返す関数ポインタ型を直接定義することはできないと思います。

別解として、暗黙の変換コンストラクタを持つ関数オブジェクトを定義すればキャストを省略できます。
特に仮想関数や継承を使う必要はないです。

C++11以降では可変引数テンプレートを使うことで、一応アダプターの汎用化はできます。

```
#include <cstdio>

template<typename... TArgs> struct MyFuncWrapper {
    using FuncPtr = MyFuncWrapper(*)(TArgs...);
    FuncPtr m_func;
    MyFuncWrapper() = delete;
    // 暗黙の変換コンストラクタ。
    MyFuncWrapper(FuncPtr p) : m_func(p) {
    }
    MyFuncWrapper operator()(TArgs... args) const {
        return m_func(args...);
    }
};

MyFuncWrapper<> f();
MyFuncWrapper<> g();

MyFuncWrapper<> f() { std::puts("f"); return g; }
MyFuncWrapper<> g() { std::puts("g"); return f; }

int main() {
    MyFuncWrapper<> x = f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        x = x();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
思ったよりずっと字面がスッキリした解決方法で驚きました。
テンプレート恐るべしですね。

Comment: と思ったら、関数のシグネチャ固定ならテンプレートいらないのか。

Comment: これ、手品の種としては裏でこっそりキャストしてる、って感じなんですかね？

Comment: すいません、using FuncPtr = MyFuncWrapper(*)(TArgs...);　の最初のカッコの中にアスタリスクが入っているのはどういう意味なのでしょうか？

Comment: 関数オブジェクトでラップする関数の引数が固定の場合はテンプレートを使わずとも書けますね。汎用的に書く場合はテンプレートですが、C++03以前では引数の数に応じて個別のテンプレート定義が必要になります。なお、引数を1つだけ受け取るコンストラクタは、explicit修飾子を付けないことでコンストラクタ呼び出しを省略でき、一見するとキャストなしで代入できているように見えます。ただし一般的に引数付きコンストラクタはコピーコンストラクタを除きexplicit修飾したほうがよいです。usingエイリアスで関数ポインタを定義するときは、(アスタリスク)が必要です。「using FuncPtr = MyFuncWrapper(*)(TArgs...);」は「typedef MyFuncWrapper(*FuncPtr)(TArgs...);」と同じですが、C++11以降はusingのほうがお勧めです。

Answer (score 1):

関数オブジェクトを使えばキャストせずに同様の形式で書けることは書けますね。

```
#include <iostream>

class Program {
    class A {
    public:
        virtual A *func() {
            static A a;
            return &a;
        }
        A *operator()() {
            return func();
        }
    };
    class F : public A {
    public:
        A *func() override {
            std::cout << "f";
            static G g;
            return &g;
        }
    };
    class G : public A {
    public:
        A *func() override {
            std::cout << "g";
            static F f;
            return &f;
        }
    };
public:
    static void exec() {
        F f;
        A *x = &f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) x = (*x)();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Program::exec();
}
```

x = (*x)() でなく x = x() を要求される場合は、次のように書けることは書けます。
C++ の参照は Java や C# の参照と違うためメンバーにポインタを持つしかない。

```
#include <iostream>

class Program {
    class A {
    public:
        A* a_ = 0;
        virtual A &func() { static A a; a_ = &a; return *a_; }
        A &operator =(const A &x) { a_ = x.a_;  return *this; }
        A &operator()() { return a_ ? a_->func() : func(); }
    };
    class F : public A {
    public:
        A &func() override { 
            std::cout << "f";
            static G g; 
            a_ = g.a_ = &g; 
            return *a_;
        }
    };
    class G : public A {
    public:
        A &func() override {
            std::cout << "g";
            static F f;
            a_ = f.a_ = &f;
            return *a_;
        }
    };
public:
    static void exec() {
        F f;
        A &x = f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) x = x();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Program::exec();
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。operator()を使えばオブジェクトを関数っぽく扱えるということですね。

Answer (score 0):

C# のデリゲートは[概要](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/#delegates-overview)を読むのが早いでしょう。

> - デリゲートは C++ 関数ポインターと似ていますが、デリゲートは完全なオブジェクト指向です。また、メンバー関数への C++ ポインターとは異なり、デリゲートではオブジェクト インスタンスとメソッドの両方をカプセル化します。

ということで、機能は２つあり、

- 関数ポインター
- メンバー関数ポインター＋対象オブジェクトのペア

となっています。
今回の例に関して言えば、 `g` や `f` は静的メソッド（C++言語における静的メンバー関数）なので、C++言語では関数ポインターで表せます。

Comment: すいません、関数ポインターのことは知っていますが、ちょっとこのケースは事情が複雑なのです。関数の戻り値の型がその関数自身になっているのが味噌でC++でコンパイルが通るコードをどう書けばいいのかわからないのです。

Comment: @Jogenara なんとなくはわかりますが、どこまで理解できていて、何を尋ねたいのかが明確ではありません。現在書けている部分までを質問文に書いてください。